# How to using two frame (together) in wxPython

Tags: wxpython

Using wxPython, how can I send data from my frame to another frame???

Answer (score 4):

I prefer something like pubsub:

http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/27/wxpython-and-pubsub-a-simple-tutorial/

Comment: thanx,i have this code but i  don't understand him,i  want more if you have ...??

Comment: pubsub is included with wxPython. There are several links with more examples at the bottom of that article.